# Prove the uniqueness of $x$ such that $b^x = y$ (part a)

Tags: real-analysis

This comes from exercise 7 Chapter 1 in Baby Rudin.

> Fix $b > 1$, $y > 0$, and prove that there is a unique real $x$ such that $b^x = y$, by completing the following outline.

(a) For any positive integer $n$, $ b^n-1 \geq n(b-1) $

(b) Hence $b - 1 \geq n(b^{1/n} - 1)$

(c) If $t > 1$ and $ n > (b-1)/(t-1)$, then $b^{\frac{1}{n}} < t$

(d) If $w$ is such that $b^2 < y$, then $b^{w + (1/n)} < y$ for sufficiently large n; to see this, apply part (c) with $t = y \cdot b^{-w}$.

(e) If $b^2 > y$, then $b^{w - (1/n)} > y$ for sufficiently large $n$.

(f) Let $A$ be the set of all $w$ such that $b^w < y$, and show that $x = \sup A$ satisfies $b^x = y$.

(g) Prove that this $x$ is unique.

---

I am currently stuck on (a). I thought I would try to show that $b^n-1$ is the supremum of the set $A = \{n(b-1)| n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$, but this seemed really weak when I tried to write the idea out on paper.

"Let $A = \{ n(b-a) | n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$. We know $A$ is not empty because $b > 1$ and $n$ is positive. We also know $A$ is bounded above by $b^n -1$ as that was given, hence there exists an element $\alpha = \sup A$."

But then I didn't know where to go from here to show $b^n-1$ as the supremum or to show some other element as the supremum(?). This seems impossibly hard and I don't how I should be changing my approach to solving these types of longer proof exercises. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First factorize the left hand side and we get
$$b^n-1=(b-1)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}+...+b^2+b+1)$$
Since $b>1$, $b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}+...+b^2+b+1\ge n$.

Therefore,$$b^n-1=(b-1)(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}+...+b^2+b+1)\ge(b-1)n$$

Answer (score 1):

Try factoring $b^n-1$. If $n=2$, then the factorization would be $b^2-1=(b-1)(b+1)$, for instance. If you play around a bit, you'll see that there's an analogous factorization for larger powers of $n$ (in particular, $b=1$ is always a root of $b^n-1$ so you can always factor a $(b-1)$ term out). Then, you should be able to use that $b>1$ to argue that one of the terms in the factorization is at least $n$, and conclude the result.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do $a)$ is by using the binomial theorem -

Let $b=1+t$

Now, as $b>1$, we have  $t>0$

Then, we can use the inequality $(1+t)^n\ge1+nt$ to get the desired result (which works as both $1$ and $t$ are $>0$)