# Show that the $x = \sup A$ satisfies $b^x = y$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

This is a follow up from an earlier part of the overall problem I asked about Rudin  Exercise 7, Chapter 1: [Prove the uniqueness of $x$ such that $b^x=y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258904/prove-the-uniqueness-of-x-such-that-bx-y)

Since this proof relies on previous parts, I will post the answers not in the previous post.

> d) If $w$ is such that $b^w < y$, then $b^{w + 1/n} < y$ for sufficiently large $n$; to see this, apply (c) in previous post with $t = y \cdot b^{-w}$

If $b^{1/n} < t$, then 
\begin{align}
b^{1/n} &< y \cdot b^{-w} = t \\
b^{1/n} \cdot b^w &< y \cdot b^{-w} \cdot b^w\\
b^{w + 1/n} &< y 
\end{align}

> e) If $b^w > y$, then $b^{w - 1/n} > y$ for sufficiently large $n$

If $b^{1/n} < t$, let $t = -yb^w$, then

\begin{align}
-yb^w &> b^{1/n} \\
b^w &> yb^{1/n} \\
b^w b^{-1/n} &> y \\
b^{w-1/n} &> y
\end{align}

> f) Let $A$ be the set of all $w$ such that $b^w < y$ and show that $x = \sup A$ satisfies $b^x = y$

Since $A$ is bounded above by $y$, there exists a supremum $\alpha = b^x = y$. Suppose by contradiction that $b^w > y$, then the supremum exists such that $\alpha = b^x = \sup y$. Suppose $b^{x-1/n} > y$ for sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Then 
\begin{align}
b^x &> b^{x-1/n} > y \\
b^{x+1/n} &> b^x > yb^{1/n}
\end{align}
but this is a contradiction to the claim that $\alpha = b^x = \sup y$. Hence $b^x = y$

> g) Prove that this $x$ is unique

The uniqueness follows from Theorem 1.21 on page 10, which states that *For every real $x > 0$ and every integer $n < 0$ there is one and only one positive real $y$ such that $y^n = x$.*

---

Comments:

- I am not too sure about f) and g). So far the entire proof has built upon the previous step, but I feel like something is off because I didn't use both d) and e) to prove f).
- I also didn't think there was anything left to prove for g) given theorem 1.21 proves the existence of unique positive roots of real numbers.

Comment: Are you allowed to use that $b^xb^y=b^{x+y}$ for real $x,y$?

Comment: @AnteP. Yes we are allowed to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part $(e)$, the right $t$ to consider should be $\frac{b^w}{y}$.

In part $(f)$, I believe you intend to say $b^x > y$ rather than $b^w > y$. $\sup y$  is incomprehensible to me. Supremum should be applied to a set. We are supposed to verify that $\sup(A)$ satisfies $b^x=y$.

Suppose we let  $x=\sup(A)$, we want to verify that $b^x=y$ is satisfied.

If $b^x<y$, then $x \in A$. From part $(d)$,  we can find $n$ large enough such that $b^{x+\frac1n} < y$, that is $x+\frac1n \in A$. This contradicts to $x$ being an upper bound.

If $b^x>y$, then from part $(e)$, we can find $n$ large enough such that $b^{x-\frac1n}>y$, that is $x-\frac1n$ is an upperbound to $A$, which contradicts to $x$ being the least upperbound.

Hence $b^x=y$.

For part $(g)$, note that theorem $1.21$ is about every real $x>0$ and every positive interger $n$, there is a unique positive real $y$ such that $\color{blue}y^n=x$. That is the positive root is unique.

In this question, the goal is for every real $b>1$ and $y>0$, we want to show we can find a unique $x$ such that $b^{\color{blue}x}=y$.

The uniqueness is due to when $b>1$, $b^x$ is an increasing function.